# View expecting IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Well im kinda new in Asp.net Mvc and im learning alone from scratch, i have a aplicattion that controls expends and earnings and what i am trying to do now is, basing on a list of earnings and expends give me the balance from a user, im having a lot of problems trying to control this and i dont know if i am doing it the right way

**Here is my model:**

```
public class Balance
    {
        public int BalanceId { get; set; }
        public List<Expense> Despesas { get; set; }
        public List<Earning> Rendimentos { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Soo what i did was, first trying to control when the user inserts a Earning or a row like, verifying if the User already exists on the database in the control method Create on the expenses and in the earning, if it doesnt exist he add the aplicationUserId and the expensive or the earning.

I want that the balance appears in every page, soo i added this to my Layout.cshtml

```
<li>@Html.Action("GetBalance", "Home")</li>
```

**it calls the controller GetBalance:**

```
public PartialViewResult GetBalance()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var balance = db.Balance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId);
        return PartialView("_GetBalance",balance);
    }
```

**Send to the view _GetBalance the balance model:**

```
@model <MSDiary.Models.Balance>

<p>Saldo: @GetBalance()</p>

@functions 
{
    HtmlString GetBalance()
    {
        decimal saldo = 0;

    if (Model.Expense.Count != 0 || Model.Earning.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Despesas)
        {
            balance += item.EarningValue;
        }
        foreach (var item in Model.Rendimentos)
        {
            balance -= item.ExpenseValor;
        }
    }

    return new HtmlString(balance.ToString());
}
}
```

What i want to know is, if there is a easyer way to do this, or what i can do to do what i want, i cant get it why my view expects something different can someone explain me what i am doing wrong?

Ps: Sorry for the long post and English, but i want to learn more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the model `@model <MSDiary.Models.Balance>` needs to be changed to:

```
@model IEnumerable<MSDiary.Models.Balance>
```

Also, the method `GetBalance` should ideally be placed in a class not in `GetBalance` partial view.  You could achieve this two ways, either through extension methods or have a Balance View Model that has the calculated balance as a property which is then passed down to your view.

As an example via an extension method:

```
public static class BalanceExtensions
{
    public static string GetBalance(this Balance balance) 
    {
       string displayBalance = "0:00";

       // Your logic here 
       return displayBalance;
    }
}
```

And then in your Partial View you can use the new HTML Helper:

```
@Html.GetBalance();
```

As an additional note I would change `List` to `IEnumerable` for expenses and earnings as it appears you are only exposing the data and not manipulating the data.

Your model would then look like:

```
public class Balance
{
   public int BalanceId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Expense> Despesas { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Earning> Rendimentos { get; set; }
   public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i dont like to use things without understanding soo i have 1 questions, IEnumerable is the same thing as list but we use one to manipulate and other just to display? Sorry for the newbie questions but im learning alone from scratch hard mode :)

Comment: @FilipeCosta - no problem :) - IEnumerable exposes an enumerator which allows you to use foreach (Just like a list), however you cannot add or remove items in the collection like you can with List. It's used primarily to expose and display the data within the view.

Answer (score 1):

@Filipe Costa A few things here.

You should probably name your view the same thing as your method. The underscore preceding the name is fairly standard so I would suggest using that same name for the method. If the name of the method and view are the same you can simply pass in the model and not have to do the name + model signature of PartialView method. It's simpler.

Aside from that your code is fine but your .cshtml partial view should have this for the first line. That will accept the list you're passing.

```
@model IEnumerable<MSDiary.Models.Balance>

<h1>@Model.BalanceId</h1>
@*Do other stuff!*@
```

Comment: Thanks, 2 questions that i have, if my Balance model has 4 atributes: 2 lists and 2 ids, why should my model be a IEnumerable?? cant it be just like this @model IEnumerable<MSDiary.Models.Balance>, and if have a partialView controler he expects always a view with a underscore + "controlerName"?

Comment: Your code looks good, ASP.Net MVC gives you a ton of control and options when displaying small portions of sites that sometimes it feels like what you are doing is wrong. Aside from this route, the only other way would possibly be doing an AJAX call in Jquery on the Document.Load, but really both ways are just fine.

Comment: It is because the way you are using entity framework. You're using a where clause which generally results in multiple. If you're looking for 1 item do a FirstOrDefault which will get you either 1 record or null. If you pass the result of a first or firstordefault query to a view it will expect a single.. as opposed to expecting the result of where which is ienumerable.

Comment: To add to this based on your code I would assume each user only has 1 balance. So you could change the where to first or firstordefault and then remove the reference to ienumerable from your view.

Comment: I understand that firstOrDefault but for example in my Expense model i had a where too, where i compared the AplicationUserId to the currenUserId and i didnt need the IEnumerable